# rxjs angular - split the return of an obserable with foreach and merge result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I perform a first call to gitlab Api which returns all starred Projects. Once completed, I want to retrieve all Milestone associated with each Project in order to append them to a custom project object and then store them somewhere.

Is there any rxjs operator which lets me do a forEach http call and wait for all calls to finish and merge the result into one?

```
getStarredProjects$(): Observable<GitlabProject[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.starredProjectsUrl).map((res: GitlabProject[]) => {
        res.forEach((project:GitlabProject)=>{
            this.getMileStones(project.id).subscribe()
        })
        return res
    })
}

getMileStones(projectId:number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.projectUrl}/${projectId}/milestones`)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build out an array of the observables you want to subscribe to, then run them simultaneously. forkJoin() will emit when all of the observables have completed.

```
getStarredProjects$(): Observable<ProjectMilestones[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.starredProjectsUrl)
        .flatMap((res: GitlabProject[]) => {
            // build out array of observables
            let observables$ = res.map(project => {
                return this.getMileStones(project.id);
            });
            // return array of observables to run simultaneously
            // spread operator here is optional, forkJoin() would also accept an array of observables
            return Observable.forkJoin(...observables$);
        })
}

getMileStones(projectId:number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.projectUrl}/${projectId}/milestones`)
}

this.getStarredProjects$.subscriber(res => {
    // res is an array of the results. (ie. res[0] is the result of the first observable in the observables$ array, res[1]...res[x])
});
```

Docs on forkJoin - https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

I'm also using flatMap here to chain the initial api call and the subsequent api calls.

---

Edit - As cartant pointed out, forkJoin either excepts an array of observables or an observable for each parameter. It may be beneficial to use the spread operator in this case to be consistent with some of the other combination operators (like concat), where you cannot pass an array of observables.

Comment: `forkJoin` will accept a single parameter that's [an array of observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/observable/ForkJoinObservable.ts#L34-L37). However, like you, I favour using the spread syntax, as it's consistent between operators. E.g. you cannot pass an array of observables to `concat`, as it'd be treated as an `ObservableInput`.

Comment: @cartant that is a good point. I've updated my answer to reflect that.